# What ways does psychology approach the study of human and animal behavior?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-science, psychology

What are the similarities in the ways a psychologist would study the behavior of a human compared to an animal?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the appliance of psychological methods. The philosophical aspect is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Ethology is the field of science that studies the behavior of animals comparatively, including humans, of course.

Sociobiology is another related term, also called "evolutionary psychology".

Both are despised by many (mostly monotheists and postmodernists). Thus, in a philosophical sense, there's no rigid frontier between us and other animals, unless you believe in a rigid interpretation of the Bible, or have any reason to try to distract and confuse the audience, instead of try to enlighten and explain things to them.

You can see some of the methods ethologists use in books like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387816232) and [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0674002350).